# FluentNHibernate mapping smalldatetime SQL data type

Tags: sql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping, smalldatetime

I have a legacy database that uses the `smalldatetime` SQL data type. That maps fine to the standard `DateTime`. However, when I use SchemaExport, it understandably generates the column with `datetime` format. What custom type should I be using in my mapping so that the generated column is `smalldatetime`?

```
   // Does not work as custom type not known       
   Map(x => x.BirthDate).Column("dtBirthDate").Not.Nullable().CustomType("smalldatetime");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it, instead of `.CustomType` you'll have to define `.CustomSqlType`

```
Map(x => x.BirthDate)
    .Column("dtBirthDate")
    .Not.Nullable()
    .CustomSqlType("smalldatetime")
    .CustomType("datetime")
```

Just tested it and it will create a database column with smalldatetime.

Comment: Perfect. Thought there was an equivalent to something like .CustomType("AnsiString") for varchar. I was going to try CustomSqlType, but I'm glad I didn't as I wouldn't have thought of adding CustomType("datetime") as well. I'm assuming this would also be the way to roll with i.e. smallint (CustomerSqlType("smallint").CustomType("int")).

Comment: And FYI for anyone else coming after, you can do the same with enum mappings with a bit of a twist (because if you're already doing a custom enum mapper, you'll already have defined the CustomType). For example, with a byte enum, Map(x => x.Season).Column("SomeTinyIntColumn").CustomType<NHibernateSomeEnumMapper>().CustomSqlType("tinyint")...